# NodeJS as Guest executable on service fabric

Tags: node.js, azure-service-fabric

I have to deploy a nodejs application as guest executable on service fabric, I hosted that on SF locally but when I try to push the code to source control, I have to push the node_modules folder along with it, but Visual studio doesn't allows you to do that since the path is too long in node_modules, Is there a way I can deploy without node_modules, I tried npm packages like nexe but none seem to work

Comment: Did you consider running node inside a container? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-containers

Comment: @LoekD thats not a possibility in our case at the moment

Comment: Move to C:\ maybe?

Comment: @Mardoxx That works but Iam in a source controlled environment, where I cant keep it on C:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after alot of research and hit/trial what we did was we zipped the node_modules folder and configured the guest executable to unzip the folder on deployment before starting the service. The unzip was done by calling a batch file before service gets started, here is a code snippet from service manifest of the guest executable that runs the batch file before starting the service:

```
<SetupEntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>MySetup.bat</Program>
    <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
    <ConsoleRedirection FileRetentionCount="10"/>
  </ExeHost>
</SetupEntryPoint>
```

Another solution can be to do npm install at the same time but we didn't want to go that path.